# How to stop VSCode from changing the bin location of my Java project to somewhere in AppData when I try to add JAR files

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar

this week I realized some new things about working with Java in VSCode, some projects had their bin location in AppData. I eventually fixed the problem, only to realize afterwards it was still happening, but only when I tried to add jar files to my project.

Here is a image of the command being run in a normal project.
[image]

And here is a picture of my problem.
[image]

This is a picture of my hierarchy.

[image]

And yes I have tried to set the bin location of my project in the settings.json in the .vscode folder.

[image]

I also added a launch.json but I don't know if its that important.

I really don't understand why this is happening, I don't use code runner, and I edited the classpath configuration here.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That argfile is in the systems temp folder, it's not the jars from the classpath itself, just a small textfile that contains the full classpath, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configuration-options you can maybe turn off that option ("shortenCommandLine") in there but I wouldn't be worried in this case

Comment: Are you telling me that this whole time I thought that was the bin location when it actually was a file to store the whole command because it was too long? Thank you so much zapl, I can't tell you how relieved I am. I was about to cry man, I have wanted to quit VSCode completely, thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your project references the `jar` package. You can `Ctrl + click` the directory link to view the contents of the file, which is actually the command to use the `jar` package.

[image]

If there is no reference to the jar file, no temporary files will appear in the command.

[image]

And your configuration in `setings.json` is correct, it will specify that the generated `.class` file is in the `bin` folder of the current directory.

```json
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
```

Comment: Thanks for help, the answer was actually also answered in the comments. Thank you though!